# How would you remotely append new objects when the local variable is in the partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my conversations index page, I can click on one of the conversations and have the messages for the conversation appear remotely. When the messages appear, there is the form to send another message within the same conversation between two users. Here is how I set this up:

> conversations/index.html.haml

```
- @conversations.each do |conversation|
  = link_to conversation_messages_path(conversation), remote: true do
    = conversation.topic
.col-lg-12
  #messages-index
```

> messages/_message.html.haml

```
- @messages.each do |message|
  = message.body
= render 'messages/form'
```

> messages/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for [@conversation, @message], remote: true do |f|
  = f.text_area :body
  = f.submit "Send"
```

> messages/_index.js.erb

```
$('#messages-index').empty().append('<%= j render @messages %>')
```

> conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < InheritedResources::Base

  def index
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end
end
```

> messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < InheritedResources::Base

    def index
        @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
        @messages = @conversation.messages
        @message = current_user.messages.build

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js 
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My problem is when I try to send a message and post the new one to the conversation like this:

> messages/_create.js.erb

```
$('#messages-index').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: "message", locals: {message: @message} %>');
```

This is not working as it will send a 500 internal error:

```
Started POST "/conversations/6/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-19 04:37:34 -0700
Processing by MessagesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "message"=>{"body"=>"dfdfd"}, "commit"=>"Send", "conversation_id"=>"6"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (15.2ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "dfdfd"], ["user_id", 4], ["created_at", "2015-10-19 11:37:34.866111"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-19 11:37:34.866111"]]
   (47.8ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered messages/_message.html.haml (5.7ms)
  Rendered messages/create.js.erb (7.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 88ms (ActiveRecord: 63.6ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/messages/_message.html.haml:1:in `_app_views_messages__message_html_haml___2837667999247155781_70076471170800'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
  actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
........
```

So how could I append it the right way so I don't get this `each` error?

> UPDATE

So I think I some how I have to get the `@messages` to be outside of the partial. Now how is that done? This is what I'm aiming for:

```
#messages-index
  - @messages.each do |message|
    = render message
```

> UPDATE 2

So I successfully solved the problem of receiving `nil` and `each` for the messages. What I had to do is assign the `conversation_id` to the message because it wasn't happening but its still not appending correctly. I'm starting to think you can't have it setup this way.

Answer (score 1):

You render partial like this:

1. `render partial: "message", locals: {message: @message}`
2. `render @messages`

But inside a partial `_message.html.haml` you use variable `@messages`. By rails conventions you should use `@message` inside `_message.html.haml'.

Note that that putting `= render 'messages/form'` is not a good thing since this partial is for a single message rendering.

---

**Update**

Here is what I mean:

> conversations/index.html.haml

```
- @conversations.each do |conversation|
  = link_to conversation_messages_path(conversation), remote: true do
    = conversation.topic
.col-lg-12
  #messages-index
.col-lg-12
  #new-message-form
```

> messages/_message.html.haml

```
  = @message.body
```

> messages/_form.html.haml

```
= form_tag conversation_messages_path(@conversation), remote: true do
  = text_area_tag :body
  = submit_tag "Send"
```

> messages/_index.js.erb

```
# Render '_message' partial for each message from @messages
$('#messages-index').empty().append('<%= j render @messages %>')

# Render '_form' partial for new message for @conversation
$('#new-message-form').empty().append('<%= j render partial: "form", locals: { conversation: @conversation }) %>')
```

Comment: Yeah I know? Changing it to `message: @messages` didn't do it nor any other variations.

Comment: I mean that inside the partial you should use `@message` (not `@messages`)

Comment: But I already use `@message` for my form? Is there another way?

Comment: Its a rails convention, I'd not advice you to go against conventions. Check rails [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) about partials.

Comment: So if I can't render the form in the partial. How else would I do it? I think I have to get the `@messages` outside of the partial to make this work but I don't know how to do that. Check my update to see what I mean.

Comment: @JohnHuntington, check my update about partials. As for controller: where does `message_params` go from? You just need to configure it to include 'conversation_id'

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up when your `@messages` is `nil`. Just put a condition in your `app/views/messages/_message.html.haml` to check if `@messages.nil?`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand?

Comment: you have the error `undefined method each for nil:NilClass` which occurs in `app/views/messages/_message.html.haml`. This comes when there are no messages, i.e. the object `@messages` is empty (`nil`). That's why you need to have a case that checks if the object is empty in which case to render something else.

Comment: When I do `if @messages.nil?` and than `else` render `@messages` I still get the same error though.

Comment: Did you put that condition before calling `each`?